# Sanitize wrong JSON

Tags: php, json

I am receiving a wrong JSON from a WS formatted like this:

```
{
"name" : {"title": "This is my wrong title "b", and then.."}
}
```

Obviously, it is wrong and `json_decode` doest work in php.
Does anybody know a way to sanitize that string and obtain something like:

```
{
"name" : {"title": "This is my wrong title \"b\", and then.."}
}
```

Comment: I don't think you can do that unless you are generating that JSON yourself. In that case you can escape the string properly by using `json_encode()` instead of string functions.

Comment: the JSON comes from an external (and famous) public WS...

Comment: Then you should send them a bug report... Which service are we talking about?

Comment: Are you sure that this is what it *actually* looks like and you're not printing it in HTML and the *actual* character is `&quot;`? Do you get the same output if you look in the source code?

Comment: No. I made also a curl: same problem...

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem... found bit of a (PHP) workaround, but it's not 100% proof:

```
 preg_match_all('/: "[^,]*",|\}/', $data, $matches );

 if ( isset ($matches[0] ))
 {
    foreach( $matches[0] AS $match )
    {
       if ( substr_count( $match, '"') > 2 )
       {
          $data = str_replace( substr($match, 2, -2), addslashes( substr($match, 2, -2) ), $data );
       }
    }
    $arr = json_decode( $data, true );
 }
```

Unfortunately this will fail if the string contains a comma... like your example.
I hope somebody will come with a better solution, i am not very happy with this one.